# How does a SqlCommand communicate with Sql Server, in detail?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am interested in monitoring and transforming SQL commands and query results using a proxy for port 1433, but I don't know much about how SQL works over the wire. Where can I find some info or documentation on this, for SQL Server, and more generally for other SQL products?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any client, including [SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx), communicates with the SQL Server using the Tabular Data Stream protocol (aka. TDS). Since this protocol falls under [EU Microsoft competition case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_Microsoft_competition_case) it is fully documented. See [Tabular Data Stream Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523.aspx) for a complete description. [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) is an alternative GNU/LGPL implementation.

Note that TDS can be implemented atop different transports, like named pipes, TCP or shared memory. The protocol is the same on all these transports.

Some products under the SQL Server 'family' are not considered do fall under the EU ruling and are undocumented.

Comment: Fab, thanks. Already found a proxy https://github.com/mclap/tdsproxy! Now I just have to wait 8 minutes to accept your answer.

Comment: Last update 4 years ago commit message "builds OK"... Sounds promising :)